# TCP client doesn't receive error connecting on non listening port

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps

I have an Azure Container App running and is listening on a public TCP port 8000 (via the load balancer) for incoming connections. When incoming connections are arriving, I serve them with data and everything goes as expected.

My problem is when I stop the server listening on that port. In that case, a client application trying to connect to my public IP address at port 8000 would expect to get an error like *'Could not connect'* but this is not happening. What is in fact happening is that the Container Apps environment seem to be forwarding the data no mater what to that port (even if there is no server listening). As such, the client connecting to that port can't understand that the server that should be listening to that port is really stopped (in order to resend the data at a later time).

**Example**:
Open a TCP client (eg. PacketSender) and try to send some data to port 6000 on your *localhost*. You should receive a *'Could not connect'* error message.

Now, in docker run the following:

```
docker run -p 6000:6000 nginxdemos/hello:plain-text
```

Try again to send some data to port 6000 via a TCP client. This time the data will be sent even though the nginxdemos container doesn't listen to port 6000 (but probably on 80).

Is it any way that I can somehow solve that issue on the server side and ensure that the clients can't connect if the server is stopped? I have devices sending thousands of data on a Container App but because they do not expect any kind of an ACK, they think that the data have been transmitted (even though they haven't) and they don't try to resend them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the docker example, it probably depends on how docker on that system implements port forwarding.

In Azure ContainerApps: no, this is not possible. There is always some component listening on the port, even if your application is not running or is restarting, provisioning, scaling, etc. The connection will be buffered until the app starts listening on the port or it times out.